# Delete network credentials

Tags: networking, credentials

I wanted to copy something to another computer using network share, and used the my credentials, now it's saved on the other computer and don't know how to remove that any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Windows:

`net use * /delete`

Reference:

```
λ net use /?
The syntax of this command is:

NET USE
[devicename | *] [\\computername\sharename[\volume] [password | *]]
        [/USER:[domainname\]username]
        [/USER:[dotted domain name\]username]
        [/USER:[username@dotted domain name]
        [/SMARTCARD]
        [/SAVECRED]
        [[/DELETE] | [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]]

NET USE {devicename | *} [password | *] /HOME

NET USE [/PERSISTENT:{YES | NO}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you see it when you run `cmdkey /list` ? If so, you can delete it using `cmdkey /delete whateverthetargetnameis` .